# How can I convert values of column into array in SQL Server?

Tags: json, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to convert value of column into an array. But I don't know how. Can anyone help?

**Below is the structure of table that I want to change.**

[image]

```
[{"entity":"Job","value":"400072 "},{"entity":"Job","value":"400087"}]
```

**Expected result:**

[image]

```
[{"entity":"Job","value":[400072, 400087]}]
```

**The code I tried :**

```
SELECT (
   SELECT ose.TaggedEntity AS 'entity', ose.TaggedEntityId AS 'value'
   FROM #OldSharedEntity AS ose
   WHERE ose.TaggedEntityId NOT IN (
      SELECT nse.TaggedEntityId 
      FROM #NewSharedEntity AS nse
   ) 
   FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
) AS json
```

Comment: What is your SQL Server version and do you want to generate a JSON array?

Comment: My SQL Server version is Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU2) (KB4340355) - 13.0.5153.0 (X64). Is it possible??

Comment: yes... but i want those value to be in comma separated [a,b,c] not as a string

Comment: the code convert that into JSON array but i want the value in [a,b,c] format...

Comment: Thank You @Zhorov I have edited m question and included the code that I tried.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU2) (KB4340355) - 13.0.5153.0 (X64).... I have already mention the version above

Answer (score 2):

If your table's name #yourtable
You can try this

```
   SELECT entity,
      (Select  JSON_QUERY('['+ STRING_AGG(value,',')+']') 
        FROM #yourtable t2 where t2.entity=entity)  value
     FROM #yourtable t 
     GROUP BY entity FOR JSON PATH
```

Comment: It's worth highlighting that `STRING_AGG` isn't available on SQL Server 2016 (the version mentioned by the question author in the question comments).